# Custom ArrayAdapter getFilter() not being called

Tags: java, android

In a simple Android app that used to use an ArrayList and an ArrayAdapter to fill an AutoCompleteTextView, I have now replaced the ArrayAdapter with a custom adapter. The reason is that I need to strip whitespace and some other characters from the entered text before searching the list (i.e., entering "O.M." should be normalised to "OM" and then the suggestions beginning with "OM" should be displayed.

I tried to do this in the following commit on GitHub: https://github.com/Natureshadow/MirWTFApp/commit/260a4deaee449cb63d3af3c446c94466b90f736c

The custom Adapter has a getFilter method that should return a custom Filter doing the normalisation, but getFilter() is never called.

What can I do to find out why it is not called, and how can I make the app use the custom Filter?

StackOverflow has some questions that describe a similar issue, but all these questions include changing the handling of the ArrayList data within the custom adapter, which I did not do.

Comment: how to make your life harder and implement `Filter` stuff at all? where do data for your `AutoCompleteTextView` come from? what is your data model?

Comment: @tinysunlight wellm there is a link to GitHub…

Comment: @pskink because the data set contains normalised strings, so the input needs to be normalised as well before searching.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19860624/2252830), pay special attention on `FilterQueryProvider`, small and easy, no need for custom adapter, custom filter and stuff like that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being a custom `ArrayAdapter` subclass which prepends a filter before the `ArrayFilter` even sees it.

The change to the main application is minimal, it just needs to instantiate the newly-christened `WtfArrayAdapter` and pass its constructor an extra argument: an object reference to the object containing the normalisation method (in the current äpp’s design, that’s the `MainActivity` class, a future refactor will do better):

```
-        ArrayAdapter acronymKeys = new ArrayAdapter(this,
-          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sorted);
+        ArrayAdapter acronymKeys = new WtfArrayAdapter(this,
+          android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sorted, this);
```

The custom `WtfArrayAdapter` must be able to call methods from `ArrayFilter` (which is `ArrayAdapter`’s internal private class), so it needs to belong to `package android.widget;`. I’ll spare you the [full imports, comments, etc.](https://github.com/Natureshadow/MirWTFApp/blob/master/app/src/main/java/android/widget/WtfArrayAdapter.java) and will reproduce the important parts below:

```
public class WtfArrayAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T> {
```

New members for:
- the pre-filter normalisation method’s object
- our internal private class’ object
- the parent’s internal private class’ object (`ArrayAdapter.mFilter` is `private`, unfortunately)

```
    private MainActivity sParent;
    private WtfArrayFilter sFilter;
    private Filter pFilter;
```

The extended constructor (we need to implement only the one we’re actually calling):
- call the inherited constructor
- store away the parent’s `mFilter` value
- instantiate our own `WtfArrayFilter`
- store away the pre-filter normalisation method’s object, as `WtfArrayFilter` will need it later

```
    public WtfArrayAdapter(Context context, @LayoutRes int resource,
      @NonNull T[] objects, MainActivity parent) {
        super(context, resource, 0, Arrays.asList(objects));
        sParent = parent;
        sFilter = new WtfArrayFilter();
        pFilter = super.getFilter();
    }
```

Override `ArrayAdapter`’s `getFilter()` method to always return our new `WtfArrayFilter`:

```
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return sFilter;
    }
```

Implementation of `WtfArrayFilter` as `Filter` subclass just like `ArrayFilter` does, and forwarding all boring (i.e. unchanged) calls to the inherited `ArrayFilter`:

```
    private class WtfArrayFilter extends Filter {
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
          FilterResults results) {
            pFilter.publishResults(constraint, results);
        }
```

We only need to change one method to do our own filtering before calling the inherited `ArrayFilter`’s filtering method:

```
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence prefix) {
            return pFilter.performFiltering(prefix == null ? null :
              sParent.normaliseAcronym(prefix.toString()));
        }
    }
}
```

Improvements welcome, I’m still a Java™ beginner.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<YourModel> listFromActivity= null;
    ArrayList<YourModel> mainList;

    public MyConstructor(Context context, ArrayList<YourModel> listFromActivity) {
        this.context = context;
        this.listFromActivity= listFromActivity;
        mainList= new ArrayList<>();
        mainList.addAll(listFromActivity);

    }    

public void filter(String charText) {
            charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
            mainList.clear();
            if (charText.length() == 0) {
                mainList.addAll(arraylist);
            } else {
                for (YourObject wp : arraylist) {
                    if (wp.getName().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText) ||
                            wp.getKey().contains(charText)) {
                        mainList.add(wp);
                    }
                }
            }
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
```

and in activity or fragment when you use this adapter

```
edittext.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                String text = mSearch.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                adaper.filter(text);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where does the mainList variable come from?

Comment: from constructor you pass your list of items on your constructor from activity/fragment

Comment: I still don't get it. The class does not have a member named mainList. If this is where I passed all the elements available, and I clear it, then how do I restore it later? I somehow do not get any of the context here… Then, what will notifyDataSetChanged() do? How does it find the mainList (again, I think mainList does not exist in ArrayAdapter…)

Comment: i added constructor now you can see where mainList came see my edited answer

Comment: Yeah, but how does notifyDataSetChanged know I put something in some class member called mainList?